# Inserting relational data with Linq to SQL results in duplicate entry error

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have drawn up a database design in the Visual Studio database diagram editor, and created all of my tables from that. I also created a Linq to SQL class and added my tables to create objects for each table. I am running into an issue when trying to insert new entries to the database.

For example:

Let's say I have two tables, Artists and Albums. A single Artist can have multiple Albums (one-to-many). Album has an ArtistID field which is a FK to the ArtistID PK in the Artist table. Their IDs are GUIDs which are auto generated by the database.

Now in my code I create a new Album object (called myAlbum) and set its Artist object to an Artist that is already in the database (myArtist).

If I do something like this:

```
DatabaseDataContext context = new DatabaseDataContext();
context.Albums.InsertOnSubmit(myAlbum);
context.SubmitChanges();
```

I end up getting a SqlException saying: "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Artist'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Artist'.
The statement has been terminated."

If I compare myAlbum.Artist to the Artist already in the database, Linq says they are equal, so it knows they are the same object.

How do I get Linq to insert the new Album object and link it to the existing Artist in the database already, without trying to insert the Artist again?

Comment: What is pk_Artist column data type?

Comment: Can you post the code where you set the artist?

Comment: I do something along the lines of:
    Album myAlbum = new Album("Greatest Hits");
    myAlbum.Artist = myArtist;

Answer (score 0):

I think that the duplicate primary key may be `GUID.Empty`. If my understanding is correct.

I would think solutions for this problem.

set default value of the `pk_artist` column to be `newid()`. That allow the primary Kerr auto generated.

Or

Explicit assign primary key to entity.

```
myAlbum.Pk_Artist = GUID.NewGiud();
context.Albums.InsertOnSubmit(myAlbum);
```

Hope this help

Comment: Actually, I already have the default value of pk_arti set to newid() and it's set to be automatically generated by the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you set the Album's `Artist` property with an object that was fetched with an other datacontext instance. Therefore, your new `DatabaseDataContext` "thinks" the Artist must be inserted.

You can either set Album.ArtistId (not the Artist object), or fetch the Artist in the same data context and add the album to its Albums collection.

By the way, `using (var context = new DatabaseDataContext()) { ... }` is better.

Comment: Ah! I think you may be onto something here. You are correct in that I did not create the Artist object within a data context. This is just a subset of my tables (for simplicity). In fact, I build a large object relationship in this way before inserting into the database. Is there any way to get Linq to "match up" objects that are already in the database?

Comment: Hardly. See the [Attach method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548978.aspx). I don't think your scenario matched the conditions described there. You better do everything within the scope of one DataContext, or work with Id's.

Comment: OK. Clearly I have some more research to do then. Thanks for you help! I think you got me on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

You need to solve the duplicate primary key first and with my test I created my primary table with a primary key of `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` and with a default value of `(newid())`.

Then when you drag your table into your Linq To SQL class project, the table class is created with everything you wanted except: The Primary Key Column should have its `Auto Generate Values` set to true but its not! By default is false when your column data type is of type `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`.
Then I dropped the column in MS SQL and recreated it with a data type of `INT` dragged it into the Linq to SQL class and it then set the column property `Auto Generate Values` to true.

So if you use the `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` you need to manually set the `Auto Generate Values` property to true.